# Stop/block the count and button once it reaches 0 - React

Tags: reactjs

I have a button to add employee with remaining number expected to be add, below the button. The defined item is data from database.

I want to block the button and stop the count once it reaches 0, as currently if I add employees more than the expected number, it will continue in negative number. I'm thinking of conditional rendering but not ensure.

```
  <div>

      <button> Add Employee </button>
      <p className="text-center">
      (+{item.expecteditemcount - totalEmployees.length} employees expected)
      </p>

  </div>
```

Comment: you can disable the button simply when count is 0

Comment: for example `<button disabled={totalEmployees.lenght}> Add Button </button>`

Comment: in disabled you should pass your exact value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disabled the button once it's reach zero

```
<button disabled={item.expecteditemcount - totalEmployees.length} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div>

      {item.expecteditemcount - totalEmployees.length && <button> Add Employee </button>}
      <p className="text-center">
      (+{item.expecteditemcount - totalEmployees.length} employees expected)
      </p>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There several options you have:

- Conditional Rendering of the button
- Disabling the button/greying it out (using the disabled prop)
- Showing an error message (conditional rendering)

From a UX standpoint, I guess that showing a helpful error message and disabling the button is the best option.